# Launch eclipse wizard from junit test?

Tags: unit-testing, user-interface, eclipse-rcp

I am writing an eclipse 3.6 RCP application with various menus, navigators, views, wizards etc.

Now I need to add a new wizard. But each time I would like to check how it looks I need to start the whole application, navigate to the menu that contains a button that launches the wizard and then I can see the result.

Is there some tutorials that show how to launch a single wizard from eg a junit test and maybe get some output from some of its pages?

Comment: I'd also be interested in this, especially doing it headless (so without SWTBot), since my wizard just extracts example code into a fresh project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for automated UI tests? Such that the tests start eclipse, open the wizard, will in some fields and check the result?

If so, take a look at http://eclipse.org/swtbot/ .

Comment: Yes I need to play with that at some point. But maybe there is a way to do this more manually from code without relying on a framework?

Comment: Of course you can start eclipse from java, open a wizard with your code, fill in values to some fields and read out some of the results to display them. But without a framework this will be MUCH work.

Comment: I was more thinking of only launching a wizard without first starting the rcp app - like to can open views from code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check the look of your wizard page, you could use the [Google WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)
This is a UI Designer that has quite nice support for SWT and is able to preview your design.